# Making a self destructive code in R

Tags: r, datetime, package, gwidgets

I was  making   a  package   in R  and   would like it  to   make it  as  a    trial  version   for  a period  of  30   days  .

Well   my  question  is   how  to  make  a  code self  destructive   depends   on  number   of  days  ??

I had  played  with   time  and  date   package  for  a  while   where  i  came  to  know  ,

`Sys.Date()`   could   give   todays  date  , so  i  get  forard  with  something below

```
today=Sys.Date()
a=today
b=a+1
if(a==today)
{ 
   print(paste("today is  sunday"))
   if(b==today){
       print(paste("today  is  monday"))
    }
```

I  know  it  is  stupid  work  whatever  i  had   done  ,  my sole  idea  was  to   fix  the  1st   use   of   package   as   starting  day   ,and  every day   it will  increment   till  30  days  ,when  it will reach   the limit   it will automatically    destroy using

`file.remove ()`  <-  through  which   I  can remove some  file   ........

May  be  I  am  clear with  my  ideas .

Sorry  for  the  novice question .

Comment: The code will be open source, so isn't this kind of moot?

Comment: Thanks  for the reply  @Thomas  ,   yes  i  know   ,  but  when   we  make  the code  as a   package   ,isnt  it  for   hiding it  from  someone  ?   Its   not  for  publishing  its for self  use ...........:)

Comment: So you plan to restrict your use of your own package to a 30 day trial?

Comment: It  is  for  some  client  to  use ,which we want  to  give him for trial    @thelatemail   :)

Comment: Why the trial period? So people will have to pay after that period to continue using the package? If you need money, giving the package away for free and asking for donations might be a better way.

Comment: Once they install the package, the source is visible.

Comment: R and its package system is designed to be open source. That is one reason for the success of the language and makes it impossible to this reliably with R.

Comment: When code is published as a package all the code is also open source, that's what makes R great and most R users like that it is open source. If you want to charge for a package then you will probably not find a very welcoming audience with R users.

Comment: Well…a binary package with individual downloads per-platform, with the majority of the code in `Rcpp` and that is generated on-the fly when downloaded with a complied-in "kill date" **could** work. It's insane, but it could work.

Comment: Another option: let them "try" via a hosted Shiny version then sell the package with a compiled-in license.

Comment: You'll get the same answers here as you get when posting to R-help. Don't post to both, it wastes everyones time.

Answer (score 2):

Add this condition to the license. ("30 days for free, after that you'll have to pay".) and expect users to comply with this.

There is really nothing else you can do.

Well, actually you can. For example, on the first occasion your code is run, save the current date to a file in a certain location (say, `"~/.datetocheck"`). Then every time your code is run, check for the existence of this file, and if it exists, compare the dates. If more than 30 days have passed, give an error message:

```
stop("Time is over! You have to pay!")
```

The problem is that nothing prevents the user from simply deleting this file.

Comment: But one of the major pillars of `R` is that all its code be open source.  If you were to try to sell a package, you'll most likely be shunned by the user community in the first place (and more than likely someone will write a better version of your tool and release it under LGPL).